# Liquibase migration on h2 database in spring boot test

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, spring-boot-test

I'm start to writing test in spring boot app.
First of all, I want to see that context successfuly up and all migrations are apllies.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Conf.class})
class ContextLoadTest{

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

Conf class:

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration()
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.mydomain"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.mydomain"})
public class GrmConfig {
}
```

configuration yml file

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username: sa
    password: sa
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/liquibase-changelog.xml
```

when I ran this test it passed successfully:

```
2023-10-26 18:57:27.727  INFO 33356 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-10-26 18:57:27.947  INFO 33356 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-10-26 18:57:28.031  INFO 33356 --- [           main] liquibase.database                       : Set default schema name to PUBLIC
2023-10-26 18:57:28.293  INFO 33356 --- [           main] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully acquired change log lock
2023-10-26 18:57:29.078  INFO 33356 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Creating database history table with name: PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
2023-10-26 18:57:29.082  INFO 33356 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
2023-10-26 18:57:29.113  INFO 33356 --- [           main] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully released change log lock
```

databasechangelog and databasechangeloglock are created, but nothing more. Migrations from db/liquibase-changelog.xml not applied.
If i add in changelog file

```xml
<include file="classpath:db/changelog/NOT_EXISTET_MIGRATION.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false" />
```

it will fail, so it shows that while context ups liquibase is initiated and `liquibase-changelog.xml` found and parsed, but tables don't created.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Config.class})
class ContextLoadTest{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println(
                jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from  databasechangelog")
        );
    }
}
```

This test also pass successfully and print that there are no rows in `databasechangelog` table, but when I ran builded jar jile, liquibase execute all scpripts.
Is there way to make liquibase execute migration scripts while context ups in spring boot tests?